# What is the best way to update files on nodes using chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a file in my chef recipe and on some node configure with chef. I want that if file will modify then this automatically changes in configured node using chef.

My approach is,
I make a recipe and put my file in template folder and put this recipe in runlist of nodes. I also cron scheduled chef-client on nodes.
So now when this files will updated and recipe uploaded on server, then files on all nodes will update.
What is the other approach to do this more efficiently.

Is it possible to do this without cron.

Eg. chef server will do it if file will modify in recipe.

Answer (score 0):

It depends - as always.

- You can use the [remote_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) resource to download files from remote locations (e.g. via HTTP). This way, chef can automatically deploy updated files, if you replace it on the source server.
- You can use use the [git](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) or [deploy](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html) resources to deploy files from a git repository. This way, you just update the git repo and chef will update the node with the new content.

But either way, chef-client only does changes during a chef run. You can trigger those through cron or run chef as service. For triggering a chef-client run automatically, you could either kick-off chef-client via SSH (e.g. automated by a Jenkins server) or you might give [Chef's push jobs](https://docs.chef.io/push_jobs.html) a try.

Comment: What if we want to do it with AWS Opswork, here we don't have chef server and chef-client, how to do it with AWS Opswork ? 
My solution is to create a layer which have a recipe that has a file which we want to change on nodes, now add this layer to required instances. Is it the correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it the correct way. By design the Chef Server doesn't perform or initiate any changes on the nodes. It's merely a repository for storing cookbooks, node attributes, etc.

Running chef-client on regular intervals is the right approach. You can do this using cron, or by running chef-client in daemon mode (`chef-client -d`), as a service.

Have a look at the [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client).

Comment: What if we want to do it with AWS Opswork, here we don't have chef server and chef-client, how to do it with AWS Opswork ? My solution is to create a layer which have a recipe that has a file which we want to change on nodes, now add this layer to required instances. Is it the correct way ?